# assigning setTimeout to global variable and clearing in separate function many times

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

The code below is meant to move a small red div up the screen when the user presses the spacebar.  In the function 'shoot' i create a new div and set a timeout before it will start moving up the screen from the 'moveLazer' function.

THE PROBLEM:  If you shoot a couple times, the 'lazerLifeCycle' variable clears when one div hits the top of the screen but also clears the timeout for the second or third div that is still moving but not at the top yet.  From what I see, using setInterval doesnt fix the problem.   I know its because lazerLifeCycle is global, but i don't see the right way to do it.  Please help!    The js and html are below.  Note they are 2 different files if you want to copy/paste and try it.  Run it in firefox or chrome.  It doesn't do anything in IE.

```
//level3.js

var lazerId = 1;

var init = function(){
    var ship = document.getElementById('randRect');
    ship.style.left = '700px';
    ship.style.top = '300px';
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    moveLeft();
  } else if(e.keyCode == 39){
    moveRight();
  } else if(e.keyCode == 32){
    shoot();
  }
}

var shoot = function(){
    lazerId = lazerId + 1;
    var ship = document.getElementById('randRect');
    width = parseInt(ship.clientWidth);
    xPos = parseInt(ship.style.left);
    middle = ((xPos + (width/2)) - 3) + 'px'; //-3 is to center it i think
    var lazer = document.createElement('div');
    lazer.id = lazerId;
    var body = document.getElementById('body');
    body.appendChild(lazer);
    lazer.style.position = 'absolute';
    lazer.style.width = '7px';
    lazer.style.height = '13px';
    lazer.style.left = middle;
    lazer.style.top = '287px';
    lazer.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    lazerLifeCycle = setTimeout('moveLazer(' + lazerId.toString() + ');', 10);
}

var moveLazer = function(lazerElementId){
    var lazer = document.getElementById(lazerElementId.toString());
    var lazerTop = parseInt(lazer.style.top);
    if( (lazerTop - 1) < 0){
        lazer.style.top = '0px';
        clearTimeout(lazerLifeCycle);
    } else {
        lazer.style.top = (lazerTop - 1) +'px'
        lazerLifeCycle = setTimeout('moveLazer(' + lazerElementId.toString() + ');', 10);
    }
}

var moveLeft = function(){
    var ship = document.getElementById('randRect');
    shipXPos = parseInt(ship.style.left);
    if( (shipXPos - 15) < 0){
        ship.style.left = 0+'px';
    } else {
        ship.style.left = shipXPos - 15+'px';
    }
}

var moveRight = function(){
        var ship = document.getElementById('randRect');
    shipXPos = parseInt(ship.style.left);
    if( (shipXPos + 15) > 1300){
        ship.style.left = 1300+'px';
    } else {
        ship.style.left = shipXPos + 15+'px';
    }
}

window.onload = init;

//level3.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>random</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .random{
                position:absolute;
                background: orange;
                padding: 7px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="level3.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="randRect" class="random"><center><-- or --><center></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/9PUaf/1/)**

Ok heres a simplified vs with changed code.

```
var shoot = function(){
    lazerLifeCycle = moveLazer(lazerId);
}

var moveLazer = function(lazerElementId){
    var lazer = document.getElementById(lazerElementId.toString());
    var lazerTop = parseInt(lazer.style.top);
    if( (lazerTop - 1) < 0){
        lazer.style.top = '0px';
    } else {
        lazer.style.top = (lazerTop - 1) +'px'
        setTimeout(function(){moveLazer(lazerElementId);}, 10);
    }
}
```

Basically you dont need to worry about clearing timeouts, since they dont reoccur unless you tell them to. Also to make it to where you can shoot more than one lazer you just need to reference the ID that was passed to `moveLazer` to begin with. Basically it will continue on until the lazer hits the top. Also allowing the support of multiple shots.
    ​